# Enabling /dev/fb0 on a CentOS 7 virtual machines?

Tags: virtual-machine, framebuffer

Recently ran into a situation where I need to install headless TeamViewer on a CentOS 7 server on Linode.  This requires `/dev/fb0` in order to function.

So far it has not been clear on how to enable the framebuffer (/dev/fb0). What do we need to do to install kernel support for a virtual machine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this is old question, but still valid.  In order to have `/dev/fb0` you need to have the frame-buffer enabled in your kernel.

To check you can grep it from kernel configuration (from currently running
`grep CONFIG_FB_ /boot/config-3.10.0-693.17.1.el7.x86_64`

For virtual environment you probably need VESA enabled so you add `grep VESA` and you should get the following output:

```
CONFIG_FB_BOOT_VESA_SUPPORT=y
# CONFIG_FB_UVESA is not set
CONFIG_FB_VESA=y
```

If you have this configured you will see the device `/dev/fb0`

**Note:** For older kernels like 4.9 you may need to add `vga=0x317` in the command-line.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, it was enabled in the kernel. I don't have the details any longer, but thanks for the post. I think the VESA info probably would have helped, but can't be sure now.

Comment: @ylluminate ah pitty that you don't have the details now.  I hope it will work if anyone needs it.

Comment: This isn't enough for me.

Comment: @konsolebox what does that mean?

Comment: @tukan `/dev/fb0` didn't populate until I specified `vga=0x317` in the command-line.

Comment: @konsolebox Ok, I'll add it to the answer.  What linux are you using?  What kernel version?

Comment: @tukan That was a 4.9. To be fair it's really old and probably new kernels would have automatically autosized the video and populated `/dev/fb0`. Also I was running it in a VM.

Comment: @konsolebox well that is probably the reason.  I'll add it as a note.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me.

Perform steps as root:

1. `systemctl set-default multi-user.target`
2. append `vga=0x317` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` line in `/etc/default/grub.conf`
3. `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`
4. add the user to the '`video`' group in `/etc/group`

   ```
   video:x:39:mario
   ```
5. reboot

Perform as user:

6. id

   ```
   uid=1000(mario) gid=1000(mario) groups=1000(mario),39(video)
   ```

ensure in `video` group (if not yet rebooted, log out and back in)

Comment: Retracting my previous comment. `vga=0x317` did it.